# Add custom @Controller to a Maven Overlay?

Tags: java, spring, maven, mitreid-connect

I'm working on an implementation of [mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server](https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server), which recommends you extend and customize the project using a Maven Overlay. I've followed the instructions, then added the following code to `webapp-overlay/src/main/java/controller/HealthcheckController.java`

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@Primary
public class HealthcheckController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/healthcheckwebapp", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public String getHealthCheck() {
        return "200 OK";
    }
}
```

However, I receive a 404 when actually trying to reach the route. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

it sends a 404 because its looking for a template called "200 ok" if you want to give a answer use @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK) and use the return to redirect to another place like return "/index"; for avoid the 404 error

i hope this helps bacause i didnt fully understood your question

Comment: Thanks @Josemtm - I'm really just trying to return the plain text "200 OK". I added the `@ResponseBody` annotation to `getHealthCheck()` to indicate I'm not trying to load a template, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I just read your answer in that case you just need to change @Controller to @RestController in this case you dont need a response body, something like this.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@Primary
public class Rest {

    @RequestMapping("/healthcheckwebapp")
    public String getHealthCheck() {
        return "200 OK";
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

On your overlay server-config.xml add this bean

```
<context:component-scan base-package="controller">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller.HealthcheckController " />
</context:component-scan>
```

And add a `@ResponseBody` annotation to `getHealthCheck()`